# How to inherit module methods in a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module

Off the bat, this feels like a dumb question... but I feel like I missing something here

How do I automatically inherit module methods in a class that belongs to a module?

```
module MyModule

  def hello
    puts "hello"
  end

  class Foo; end
  class Bar; end
end
```

Halp

```
f = MyModule::Foo.new
f.hello
# NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for #<MyModule::Foo:0x007f8d8b010200>

b = MyModule::Bar.new
b.hello
# NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for #<MyModule::Bar:0x007f8d8b03a140>
```

---

I feel like I shouldn't have to do this

```
module MyModule
  class Foo
    include MyModule
  end
end
```

Otherwise what's the point of putting the class in the module?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand quite well what are you trying to accomplish doing that. As far as I'm concern, `Modules` in Ruby are used as namespaces and mixins.

How do you expect that all classes inside a module contain the module functions defined before? For me, that doesn't make sense. Probably, you're trying to force that behavior which is not a feature in Ruby.

Normally, you'll be compliant with languages constraints, create a module, functions inside them which share some common objective, and later `include` them inside a class to extend its behavior --another way to circumvent the lack of multiple inheritance.

I don't see the beauty of what you're trying to accomplish. As I said, modules are used as namespaces and mixin, other than that, is not what Ruby's community intended for them.

About the point of putting a class in a module, I guess is no other than *modularity* and object oriented programming practices.

Comment: /me laments, "okaaayyyyy" T.T

Comment: After reading your input, I arrived at a new solution (posted as a separate answer). +1 for your advice.